# Best way to extract the Date from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, date, datetime

I am trying to extract the date from a string. I used to be able to just pull the entire line, but the company sending the data keeps adding characters to the front/back of the date, which causes my code to stop functioning till I fix it. I am getting mixed reviews searching on if I should use regex or datetime module. Here is what I am currently using, which you can see if cumbersome and not efficient.

```
line = ' .10/10/2020<=x'

date = line.strip().replace('.', '').replace('<', '').replace('=', '').replace('x', '')
```

edit:

I ended up taking Yash's regex and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not extract using regex? this will only work for format xx/xx/xxxx. need to change regex if multiple formats are found

```
import re
line=' .10/10/2020<=x'
a=re.search("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})", line)
print(a.group(1))
```

Comment: This works. I was using re.compile and then i was getting errors on my print. Thanks